# Rename multiple files with mv to change the extension

Tags: rename, mv

I want to rename files to change their extension, effectively looking to accomplish

```
mv *.txt *.tsv
```

But when doing this I get :

> *.tsv is not a directory

I find it somewhat strange that the first 10 google hits show `mv` should work like this.

Comment: You should explain **how** you want to rename those files exactly.

Comment: Well i have files with an extension of *.gappedPeak and want to rename them to *.bed. they are all in the same directory it should be very simple but a full for loop was needed for me to succeed

Comment: What you found on Google applies to MSDOS I think.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This answer won't help you change the extension, but it will help you understand why your command is not doing what you expect.

When you issue the command:

```
mv *.txt *.tsv
```

the shell, lets assume bash, *expands* the wildcards ***if*** there are any matching files (including directories). The list of files is passed to the program, here `mv`. If no matches are found the unexpanded version is passed.

Again: the *shell* expands the patterns, not the program.

---

Loads of examples is perhaps best way to understand why this won't work. So here we go:

#### Example 1:

```
$ ls
file1.txt file2.txt

$ mv *.txt *.tsv
```

Now what happens on the `mv` line is that *the shell* expands `*.txt` to the matching files. As there are no `*.tsv` files that is not changed.

The `mv` command is called *with two special arguments*:

- `argc`: Number of arguments, including the program.
- `argv`: An array of arguments, including the program as first entry.

In the above example that would be:

```
 argc = 4
 argv[0] = mv
 argv[1] = file1.txt
 argv[2] = file2.txt
 argv[3] = *.tsv
```

The `mv` program checks to see if the last argument, `*.tsv`, is a directory. As it is not, the program can not continue as it is not designed to concatenate files. (combine all the files into one.) Nor can it create directories on a whim.

As a result, it aborts and reports the error:

> ```
> mv: target ‘*.tsv’ is not a directory
> ```

---

#### Example 2:

Now if you instead say:

```
$ mv *1.txt *.tsv
```

The `mv` command is executed with:

```
 argc = 3
 argv[0] = mv
 argv[1] = file1.txt
 argv[2] = *.tsv
```

Now, again, `mv` checks to see if `*.tsv` exists. As it does not, the file `file1.txt` is moved to `*.tsv`. That is: the file is renamed to `*.tsv` with the asterisk and all.

```
$ mv *1.txt *.tsv
‘file1.txt’ -> ‘*.tsv’

$ ls
file2.txt *.tsv
```

---

#### Example 3:

If you instead said:

```
$ mkdir *.tsv
$ mv *.txt *.tsv
```

The `mv` command is executed with:

```
 argc = 3
 argv[0] = mv
 argv[1] = file1.txt
 argv[1] = file2.txt
 argv[2] = *.tsv
```

As `*.tsv` now is a directory, the files end up being moved there.

---

Now: using commands like `some_command *.tsv` when the intention is to actually keep the wildcard one should always quote it. By quoting you prevent the wildcards from being expanded if there should be any matches. E.g. say `mkdir "*.tsv"`.

#### Example 4:

The expansion can further be viewed if you do, for example:

```
$ ls
file1.txt file2.txt

$ mkdir *.txt
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘file1.txt’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘file2.txt’: File exists
```

---

#### Example 5:

Now: the `mv` command can and does work on multiple files. But if there are more than two the last one has to be a target directory. (Optionally you can use the `-t TARGET_DIR` option, at least for GNU mv.)

So this is OK:

```
$ ls -F
b1.tsv  b2.tsv  f1.txt  f2.txt  f3.txt  foo/

$ mv *.txt *.tsv foo
```

Here `mv` would be called with:

```
 argc = 7
 argv[0] = mv
 argv[1] = b1.tsv
 argv[2] = b2.tsv
 argv[3] = f1.txt
 argv[4] = f2.txt
 argv[5] = f3.txt
 argv[6] = foo
```

and all the files end up in the directory `foo`.

---

As for your links. You have provided one (in a comment), where `mv` is not mentioned at all, but `rename`. Do you have more links or man pages that you could share where your claim is expressed?

Answer (score 49):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but in case you were looking for another way to rename the files compared to your work-around loop, why not use `find`? I have used this command many times to replace file extensions in large directories with hundreds of thousands of files in it. This should work on any POSIX-compliant system:

```
find . -name "*.gappedPeak" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.gappedPeak}.bed"' _ {} \;
```

Command Breakdown:

> 1. '**`.`**' => search path starting at current directory marked by ' . '
> 2. `-name` => set find match name (in this case all files that end with
>      `.gappedPeak`)
> 3. `-exec` => execute the following command on every match
> 4. `sh -c` => 'exec' creates an independent shell environment for each match
> 5. `mv "$1" "${1%.gappedPeak}.bed"` => `mv` first variable (denoted by **$1**),
>      which is the current file name, to new name. Here I do a substring match and delete; so take first var again, **$1** and use `%` to delete `.gappedPeak` from the string. The `.bed` at the end just concatenates the remaining variable, which in the example below would now be `testNumber`, with `.bed`, creating the new `testNumber.bed` filename.
> 6. The underscore is a placeholder for **$0**
> 7. The `{}` is replaced by each (`*.gappedPeak`) filename found
>      by the `find` command, and becomes **$1** to the `sh` command.
> 8. `\;` marks the end of the `-exec` command. 
>      You can also use `';'` or `";"`.

Example:

```
[user@before]# ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test1.gappedPeak
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test2.gappedPeak
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test3.gappedPeak
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test4.gappedPeak
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test5.gappedPeak

[user@after]# ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test1.bed
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test2.bed
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test3.bed
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test4.bed
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan 26 11:40 test5.bed
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  With a [bash guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and your explanation I was able to get everything.

Comment: Works like a charm. Here's another simplified example for `file.abc` -> `blub.xyz` in multiple sub dirs: `find . -name "file.abc" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(dirname $1)/blub.xyz"' _ {} \;`

Comment: how do you know $0 is placeholder? are there other placeholders? @AdminBee

Comment: @cosmicsage Although you should direct your question at the _author_ of the answer (devnull), you can take a look at the bash manpage in the section `ENVIRONMENT`.

Comment: this answer works very well when i have to rename 400 .js files to .jsx files in React. 
just posting my code as an example
`find . -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.js}.jsx"' _ {} \`

Answer (score 9):

`mv *.txt *.tsv` doesn't work; `mv` can rename only one file at a time. You have either misunderstood the explanations or they are wrong.

`mmv` and `rename` can rename several files at once. But there are two versions of `rename` around which are called differently. There should be plenty of questions about that here.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html The first hit on google is saying that mv should work as well thats why i found it so strange

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw I don't know what you read there. The examples use `rename`, not `mv`.

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrong HTML. This was the one https://www.udemy.com/blog/rename-a-file-in-linux/

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw Embarrassing. These people offer courses? Unfortunately I don't see a contact possibility there. You can easily check whether this works. But in `mv *.txt *.tsv` `mv` does (usually) not see `*.txt` or `*.tsv` but the shell-expanded file names. The number of files these wildcards expand to would be "random". The only situation where this works is if there is a file with the name `*.txt` which shall be renamed to (literally) `*.tsv` (without quoting the `bash` option `nullglob` must not be set).

Comment: Or worse. If one have *one* file named e.g. `foo.txt` and *one* named `baz.tsv` the `mv *.txt *.tsv` will overwrite the existing `.tsv` file ...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Indeed unbelievable that this can happen especially if they provide courses. This is the entire reason i opened this question just to see all of your opinions on this.

Answer (score 6):

## `rename(1)`

`rename` is a perl script by Larry Wall the maker of perl. It takes a Perl regex and operates on the file name.

```
rename 's/\.txt$/.tsv/' *.txt
```

## Installation

### Debian/Ubuntu

If you need to install `rename` on Debian/Ubuntu you can do

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Comment: This worked fine for me in a folder with 20 000 files, but in a folder with 80 000 files, the "argument list too long" error appeared so I had to find another way.

Comment: @user985366 one way to get around that is to use xargs. `find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs rename 's/\.txt$/.tsv/'`

Answer (score 4):

For example, if you have `asd.txt` and `qwe.txt` files in the directory when you run the command `mv *.txt *.tsv`, it tries to move these two files into a directory named `*.tsv`.  Because there is no such directory, it gives an error.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies partially. Still i find it strange that i see so many manual pages where they claim mv should work on multiple.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently the easiest way under Linux OS is :

[image: manual rename]

1. Click on file
2. Press F2 (rename)
3. alter the file name as you like
4. press <ENTER>

I guess sometimes DOS does win.  :)

Comment: (1) Your answer is unclear.  I guess you mean to go to each file with the specified “old” extension (finding them all manually) and then rename each one (manually).  Your presentation is particularly unclear in that you don’t show renaming `file1.txt` to `file1.tsv`.  (2) It’s implicit in the question (and in the other answers) that the objective is to find ***all*** the files that have the specified “old” extension ***automatically*** and then rename them all to have the same name but with the new extension, and do this all in one operation … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (compared to your answer, which would require 987 actions if you have 987 files).